# add to cart button in CMS page

Tags: magento-2.1, addtocart, cms-pages

In Magento2.1, I'm able to load a product in CMS page using:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
```

Then I'm trying (without any luck) to display the add-to-cart link using:

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**p.s.** I saw many Q&A about this topic but none of them seems to work in my project.

**EDIT**

I've just found the following that actually displays the link, but it completely breaks the layout.

```
$listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
$addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);

echo $addToCartUrl;
```

**EDIT 2**

so I did some tests and got inconsistent results.

I was able to display an add-to-cart button with the following:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
    $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
?>

<form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <button type="submit"
            title="Add to Cart"
            class="action tocart primary dark">
            <h2>Add to Cart</h2>
        </button>
 </form>
```

This button does not add anything to the cart untill I click on the link built with:

```
<a href="<?php echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>">ADD TO CART</a>
```

After that, the JS button start working correctly.. I'm currently at a dead end

Comment: You cannot use Mage class in Magento 2

Comment: Ok, what shall I use instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Mage` class, which has been removed in `Magento 2`. The `Magento 2` equivalent of

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>
```

is as below:

**Method 1**

```
<?php echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getAddUrl($product) ?>
```

**Method 2:**

Also, Note that you should avoid using `Object Manager` in `Magento 2`. It is not a good practice. So, to avoid using `Object Manager` you have to write following in your template's `Block` File:

```
protected $_cartHelper;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $cartHelper
) {
   $this->_cartHelper = $cartHelper;
}

public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = []) {
   return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

For method 2, you can use `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` class's `getAddToCartUrl` function as your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Method1 actually display the links and doesn't break the layout, but if I follow the link I see the cart without any product added to it

Comment: Try to set Product store before passing product as argument to getAddUrl . You can debug addProduct function of vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart.php file to figure out why it's not adding product to your cart

Comment: Thanks again, how can I set Product store and website Id?

Comment: If you are using method 1 then Try updated answer's method 1  pls

Comment: the updated answer breaks the layout and does not echoes anything

Comment: what error do u get.. did u try to debug the function i mentioned ?

Comment: I updated my Q with some tests I tried so far

Comment: Anyone help me, How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f