# Magento 2: add product (catalog) to cart when button is clicked

Tags: magento2

In a custom widget that displays on main page and category pages, I need to have a button clicking on which should add product catalog (having it's own sku) to the cart. Can you please suggest how to go about this?

Path of the custom widget is

```
app/code/<vendorname>/<modulename>/view/frontend/templates/widget/<widgetname.phtml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add the catalog product to the cart with the following code from [add to cart button in CMS page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150884/add-to-cart-button-in-cms-page)

```
        <?php
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(6109);
            $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
            $addToCartUrl =  $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        ?>
        <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php echo $addToCartUrl; ?>" method="post">
            <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
            <button type="submit"
            title="Add to Cart"
            class="action tocart primary dark">
            <h2>Add to Cart</h2>
            </button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

**just add the below code in your widget phtml file where ever you want.**

```
 <?php
$item_id = 1; //product id
$_product = $block->getProductDetails($item_id);
    $postDataHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper');
    $postData = $postDataHelper->getPostData($block->getAddToCartUrl($_product), ['product' => $_product->getId()]);
    ?>
    <button class="action tocart primary" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postData; ?>' type="button" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?>">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span></button>
```

**In your block you can get the product collection like below code.**

```
public function __construct(
 \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
  array $data = []
    ){
............
}
public function getProductDetails($productId)
    {
        $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        return $product;
    }
```

Please make ensure product collections **$_product** getting from widget block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Where is $_product defined? OR Where would the value for $_product come from?

Comment: please check my updated code. it is come from widget block

Comment: please tell if you have any issue.

Comment: Is there no need to create the instance of the constructor before I call getProductDetails? If we need to create instance, what should be passed to the constructor?